# Filter a model on the add page for that model (Django)

Tags: django-admin, django-admin-filters

I need to attach a filter to a model when the user is adding a new entry via the admin page, similar to the way that there is a filter for permissions on the add group page of the admin page. From what I have researched it seems like I need to use a formfield_for_ … method, but I cant seem to be able to make that work

Comment: This question is too vague. Could you include your model and explain which field you would like to filter along with the conditions of the filter?

Comment: I fugured it out. I just had to add an autocomplete_fields = [field_I_wanted_filtered]